# If the RPM of an AC generator doubles, and its frequency and voltage doubles, how much does its current decrease?

Tags: power-supply, power, current, ac, education

From what I understand, if the rotation rate of an alternating current generator increases, its voltage increases at the same rate...

I also have learned that the total power produced increases logarithmically (I believe), so that it also increases with higher RPM, but not as much...

Is there a universal equation or formula relating the RPM or Hertz of an AC unit with its resulting power output?

Answer (score 4):

> From what I understand, if the rotation rate of an alternating current generator increases, its voltage increases at the same rate...

Open circuit voltage, yes

> I also have learned that the total power produced increases logarithmically (I believe), so that it also increases with higher RPM, but not as much...

Not sure where you get that idea from

> Is there a universal equation or formula relating the RPM or Hertz of an AC unit with its resulting power output?

No

An AC generator has two power limits

- The power of the prime mover turning it
- The maximum current that can flow into the load

The maximum current is complicated, as it will be limited by

- The impedance of the generator and load
- The maximum temperature that the generator can reach without failing

The temperature limit allows higher power operation for short bursts, with the heat absorbed by the mass of the windings, compared to lower power for continuous operation, where the heat has to be continuously dissipated.

The impedance of the generator will depend on its design, but generally the AC impedance rises with frequency, as the machine will have some inductance, as well as resistance. Some specially wound generators (compulsators) have a very low inductance, and are used as energy storage devices for very high power pulse outputs like rail guns. A bicycle dynamo is the opposite extreme, with a high inductance, that gives a more or less constant current output with frequency.

Generally, the available power from a generator rises as the frequency rises, as the voltage increases proportionally with speed. Cooling generally improves with speed, so the continuous permitted current could also rise somewhat with frequency, giving a higher than linear increase in power output with speed, at least at low speed. At higher speeds, the power dissipated in windage becomes significant, as it increases as the cube of speed.